# « Il en soit ainsi »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Dans cette phrase extraite de la préface de Thierry Laget pour [cette édition](http://www.gallimard.fr/Catalogue/GALLIMARD/Folio/Folio-classique/Prescriptions/Madame-Bovary) de *Madame Bovary*:

> Elle n'est pas la loi divine, mais celle du romancier, *qui a voulu
>   qu'il en soit ainsi*, parce que deux autorités supérieures, la forme et
>   l’idée, l'exigeaient.

(p. 39)

Ce morceau de phrase, *qui a voulu qu'il en soit ainsi*, peut être traduit en anglais comme ça, je crois :

> Who wanted [the novelist] things to remain the same.

C'est bien comme ça ?

**Note**

Il y a deux expressions idiomatiques avec *ainsi* : *il en est ainsi* et *puisqu'il en est ainsi*. Elles n'ont pas le même sens, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: "En être ainsi" is not exactly "to remain the same" to me. It's "to be as it is", if it means something in English, I dunno. You could say "qui a voulu que ce soit comme cela".

Comment: Careful with "c'est correct", it has another meaning. Using, c'est bien comme ça is more idiomatic in French. "the law of the novelist who wished it to be so". être ainsi: to be like that, to be so, in formal English.

Comment: With the notion of [“la loi qui veut que”](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/la%20loi%20qui%20veut%20que) in mind, I think it’s possible that “qui” refers not to the novelist, but to his **law**, w/“qui”=“that”(not “who”) & w/“a voulu”=more like “called for” or “stated”(not so much “wanted”): “It’s not divine law, but the novelist’s law that called for it/things to be this way//stated that ... it be like that/it be so/it be as it is/things be as they are” (I see the temptation to replace some/all of those “BE”s w/“remain” but I agree w/Simon that it wouldn’t be exactly the same)

Comment: La traduction n'est pas correcte, les deux expressions ont le même sens (à "puisque" près), et "il en soit ainsi" dans le titre n'est pas correct, un "que" est nécessaire.

Answer (score 5):

Non, comme indiqué dans les commentaires, cette traduction ne reflète pas l'idée du texte.

Je pense qu'il y a confusion quant à la signification de "*qu'il en soit ainsi*".
Pour te donner une idée, si cette expression était utilisée seule, "*Qu'il en soit ainsi.*" pourrait être traduit en anglais par "*So be it.*"

Dans le cas que tu donnes, je traduirais par "*Who[the novelist] wanted it[the law] to be the way it is.*", ou bien encore plus court : "*Who wanted it to be this way.*"

Comment: qu'il en soi ainsi n'est pas so be it. The novelist wanted it to be so. So is the literary or formal way to write it.

Comment: You are right, it simply is a more literal translation while my answer focused more on the meaning of the expression.

Comment: Your answer is literal, mine is what one would actually use.

Comment: Wait, I never suggested the OP should use "so be it" in this case. This is the way it would be translated if it was found in a text as a single sentence. Like if someone would answer "Qu'il en soit anisi!", it would become "So be it!" in the translated text. Since we were talking about an expression, I gave the corresponding expression in english to make the meaning clear, that's all. My actual suggestion is in my last paragraph.

Comment: @Lambie Seul, "*Qu'il en soit ainsi*" se traduit bien par "*So be it*". Par contre en subordonnée, "il a voulu *qu'il en soit ainsi*" a effectivement une traduction différente (mais "*en être ainsi*" a bien le même sens).

Comment: @Teleporting Goat It simply does not translate to **so be it**. So be it is a stand-alone phrase, and cannot be incorporated into a sentence in English and certainly not here...

Comment: @Lambie *So be it* is a standalone phrase. Like Patsuan and I said, it translates to the standalone phrase "*Qu'il en soit ainsi*". I thought it was clear. Neither Patsuan or I ever claimed it could go in a sentence. See [this](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/ainsi), I don't know what else you need.

Comment: @Teleporting Goat No, it is a clause in a sentence here, not a standalone phrase. That's my whole point. That is why it cannot be So be it.

Comment: @Lambie No one ever said it could translate to "So be it" *here*, I don't know how you understood it that way (considering every one repeatedly said the opposite). I edited the answer anyway to remove any possible confusion.

Comment: @Patsuan `ou bien encore plus court : "Who wanted it to be this way."` - ou, toujours plus court, *who wanted it that way* ;)